# CSS IE7 Background

Tags: html, css

I have the CSS:

```
.dot-preview {
    background: url("../images/dot.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

but IE 7/8/9 don't show the image.

Called from:

```
<img class="dot-preview">
```

What is wrong with my code? It is IE bug?

Comment: How come you are using both the HTML Element/Tag of Img as well as CSS background to display your image. Possibly the image file is not in the images directory. Double check your relative path to the image file as it is relative to the CSS file and not the HTMl file. Also your img element/tag is missing the src attribute. Give it a alt attribute as well and see if the alternative text gets displayed instead of the image when the image file is itself missing.

Comment: Image are correct, src are a empty image now, width and height are setted, not work.

Comment: You mean `src=""` on the img? I'm not sure the browsers are supposed to show empty images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning background to empty image tag makes very little sense. Use `<div>` element instead and the key is to give it proper width and height:

```
<div class="dot-preview"></div>
```

And in the CSS:

```
.dot-preview {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    /* ... */
}
```

Put the correct image width and height and it should work fine.

Comment: Make sense, it is for a jquery script and image src are changed with hover. If I change to div, it stop working.

Comment: So assigning the image source will hide whatever background you were trying to apply.

Comment: Sorry, image background are changed with hover.

Comment: @GabrielSantos can you reproduce this in jsFiddle?

Comment: @GabrielSantos what dots? I can't see any difference between Chrome and IE9 when viewing that site..

Comment: Chrome and IE 7/8/9 render a square. See the website with Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: @GabrielSantos Yeah, saw it now... as far as I could see it's low level rendering of the browser - [changing to div](http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/nQpWy/1/) solve the issue are you sure you can't edit the jQuery code?

Comment: @GabrielSantos sorry, so I fear you'll have to find other plugin that isn't Firefox only.

Comment: may I change with my JS an <img class="change-to-div"> tag into <divs>.

Comment: @GabrielSantos you can try have `$(".change-to-div").replaceWith("<div class=\"change-to-div\"></div>")` but not sure it would work.

Comment: I've got permission to make the change, replace the `<img>` tag for the `<div>` tag solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set a height and width to your image.

```
.dot-preview {
    background: url("../images/dot.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

you might also want to have a transparent 2x2px image in the src of your image, or else IE will show a "not found" icon

**EDIT:**

in IE, transparent placeholders should be 2x2px wide. as they create a visual bug if they are 1px wide

Comment: i had a typo in the width line, did you copy paste it?
if so, try again, i fixed the ; at the end

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

**HTML**

```
<img class="dot-preview" />
```

**CSS**

```
.dot-preview {
    background: url("../images/dot.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display:block;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

You can change the width and height as you like

Comment: Doesn't work. Width, height and display block defined, and src are a 1 x 1px image.

Comment: @Gabriel Santos: This code works with me in IE7,8 and ff fine . if the image is small , you can change no-repeat to repeat .

Answer (score 0):

```
.dot-preview {
    background-image: url("../images/dot.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display:block;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

Basically you should have `display block` for the class you want to have background-image, or you can have this whole thing in div with class `.dot-preview`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

**HTML**

```
<img class="dot-preview" />
```

**css**

```
.dot-preview {
    background:#000 url("../images/dot.png") repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```